# How to write complex XML Element or Attribute String

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I am trying to write an XML file from Visual Studio (.Net Visual Basic Language) that has a complex Node and I am unable to figure out the proper syntax.

I have been trying a combination of the WriteAttributeString and WriteElementString methods below but I am not very familiar with XML generation.

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("Version", "1.4.1.0")
writer.WriteElementString("xsi", "schemalocation", "http: //www.witsml.org/schemas/1series  ../xsd_schemas/obj_stimJob.xsd")
```

I have included an example of what it should look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stimJobs version="1.4.1.0" 
   xsi:schemalocation="http://www.witsml.org/schemas/1series../xsd_schemas/obj_stimJob.xsd" 
   xmlns="http://www.witsml.org/schemas/1series"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to understand XML namespaces concept first to deal with XmlReader. Just in order to understand what you need to acomplish.

```
Dim xsiNS As String = "http://xxx"
writer.WriteStartElement("stimJobs", "http://yyy")
writer.WriteAttributeString("version", "1.4.1.0")
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", Nothing, xsiNS)
writer.WriteAttributeString("schemalocation", xsiNS, "http://zzz")
'Write your content here
writer.WriteStartElement("subelementwithxsi", xsiNS)
writer.WriteEndElement()    '/subelementwithxsi
writer.WriteStartElement("subelementwithrootns")
writer.WriteEndElement()    '/subelementwithrootns
'Close parent element
writer.WriteEndElement()    '/stimJobs
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Perfect for me having no prior experience in XML. Thank you.